# Spring Boot OAuth2: extract JWT from cookie for authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm using spring boot to build a simple auth process for my app.
I have AuthorizationServerConfig & ResourceServerConfig setup, my frontend is a SPA. When I hit /oauth/token route, I got a JWT back which I previously  stored in localStorage, and when I try to hit the resource server route, I have authorization header setup with this JWT, everything works.

But now I want to do authorization with JWT stored in the cookie, how I can config it so that it works with my current authorization/resource server config? I googled for a while and the best I can find is to set up a customize token extractor, but I'm not sure how to get it right, thank you in advance.

-------------- update --------------

I have @EnableAuthorizationServer and @EnableResourceServer on, and the EnableResourceServer setup an OAuthAuthenticationProcessingFilter automatically, this filter user bearer header authentication which uses a bearer token extractor to extract from the request header, I looked at the source code, it's hardcoded into the library, how I can customize this filter to extract JWT from the cookie?

Answer (score -1):

Read cookie value from the request object and parse jwt manually.
Here is sample code

```
public Jws<Claims> parseJWT(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie cookie =  WebUtils.getCookie(request, "Token cookie name");
    if(cookie == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("Token not found from cookies");
    }
    String token  = cookie.getValue();
    return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey("your signing Key").parseClaimsJws(token);
}
```

you can create request filter and check jwt.

Answer (score -1):

There are many implementation for JWT. Am using this. `io.jsonwebtoken`

I am adding a Token Helper Class which has methods to validate, generate, refresh token. You can focus on the JWT extraction part.

Jar Dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
    <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0</version>
</dependency>
```

JWT Helper Class. It contains methods to validate, refresh, generate token.

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.test.dfx.common.TimeProvider;
import com.test.dfx.model.LicenseDetail;
import com.test.dfx.model.User;


@Component
public class TokenHelper {

    protected final Log LOGGER = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Value("${app.name}")
    private String APP_NAME;

    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    public String SECRET;    //  Secret key used to generate Key. Am getting it from propertyfile

    @Value("${jwt.expires_in}")
    private int EXPIRES_IN;  //  can specify time for token to expire. 

    @Value("${jwt.header}")
    private String AUTH_HEADER;


    @Autowired
    TimeProvider timeProvider;

    private SignatureAlgorithm SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = SignatureAlgorithm.HS512;  // JWT Algorithm for encryption


    public Date getIssuedAtDateFromToken(String token) {
        Date issueAt;
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            issueAt = claims.getIssuedAt();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not get IssuedDate from passed token");
            issueAt = null;
        }
        return issueAt;
    }

    public String getAudienceFromToken(String token) {
        String audience;
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            audience = claims.getAudience();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not get Audience from passed token");
            audience = null;
        }
        return audience;
    }

    public String refreshToken(String token) {
        String refreshedToken;
        Date a = timeProvider.now();
        try {
            final Claims claims = this.getAllClaimsFromToken(token);
            claims.setIssuedAt(a);
            refreshedToken = Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setExpiration(generateExpirationDate())
                .signWith( SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM, SECRET )
                .compact();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not generate Refresh Token from passed token");
            refreshedToken = null;
        }
        return refreshedToken;
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        String audience = generateAudience();
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setIssuer( APP_NAME )
                .setSubject(username)
                .setAudience(audience)
                .setIssuedAt(timeProvider.now())
                .setExpiration(generateExpirationDate())
                .signWith( SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM, SECRET )
                .compact();
    }



    private Claims getAllClaimsFromToken(String token) {
        Claims claims;
        try {
            claims = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                    .parseClaimsJws(token)
                    .getBody();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("Could not get all claims Token from passed token");
            claims = null;
        }
        return claims;
    }

    private Date generateExpirationDate() {
        long expiresIn = EXPIRES_IN;
        return new Date(timeProvider.now().getTime() + expiresIn * 1000);
    }

    public int getExpiredIn() {
        return EXPIRES_IN;
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        User user = (User) userDetails;
        final String username = getUsernameFromToken(token);
        final Date created = getIssuedAtDateFromToken(token);
        return (
                username != null &&
                username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) &&
                        !isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(created, user.getLastPasswordResetDate())
        );
    }

    private Boolean isCreatedBeforeLastPasswordReset(Date created, Date lastPasswordReset) {
        return (lastPasswordReset != null && created.before(lastPasswordReset));
    }

    public String getToken( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        /**
         *  Getting the token from Authentication header
         *  e.g Bearer your_token
         */
        String authHeader = getAuthHeaderFromHeader( request );
        if ( authHeader != null && authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return authHeader.substring(7);
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String getAuthHeaderFromHeader( HttpServletRequest request ) {
        return request.getHeader(AUTH_HEADER);
    }


}
```

Finally your controller class

```
public void validateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Cookie cookie =  WebUtils.getCookie(request, "TOKEN_NAME");
    if(cookie == null) {
        throw new SecurityException("JWT token missing");
    }
    String token  = cookie.getValue();  // JWT Token

    Claims claims =   TokenHelper.getAllClaimsFromToken(token); // claims will be null if Token is invalid

}
```