# How to get username from JWT token while requesting for another service after authentication?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, jwt, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am developing a spring boot application having front end with angular6 and using Eureka for service registry and zuul for authentication gateway, both as separate service. I am using jwt for authentication.

When I hit the url localhost:8080/dis/academics/complaint/getMyComplaints with authorization header having value jwt token, then it goes to gateway service and then gateway forwards this to academics service after valid authentication at gateway.

Now I want to get username from token in academics service. How can I get it?

Controller in Gateway Service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/dis")
public class AuthRestAPIs {

@PostMapping("/signin")
public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest) {

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    String jwt = jwtProvider.generateJwtToken(authentication);
    //UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
    UserPrinciple userPrincipal = (UserPrinciple) authentication.getPrincipal();
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new JwtResponse(jwt, userPrincipal.getUsername(), userPrincipal.getUserType(), userPrincipal.getAuthorities()));
}
}
```

Controller in Academics Service

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/complaint") 
public class ComplaintsController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMyComplaints", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public <T, U> Object[]  getMyComplaints(Authentication authentication)
{
    String username = authentication.getName();

    //System.out.println(username);

    String user_type = "student";

    List<Object> complaints = new ArrayList<>();

    if(user_type.equals("student"))
    {
        Collections.addAll(complaints, cleanlinessComplaintRepository.findByCreatedBy(username));
        Collections.addAll(complaints, leComplaintRepository.findByCreatedBy(username));
        Collections.addAll(complaints, facultyComplaintRepository.findByCreatedBy(username));
        Collections.addAll(complaints, otherComplaintRepository.findByCreatedBy(username));
    }

    return complaints.toArray();
}
}
```

I have tried using Authentication class but getting null value. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add generated jwt token?

Comment: when you are logged in store the details(jwt token) as well as others details like username and what ever data you are getting in session storage. and get that data from session storage where ever u want.

Comment: First request, client sends id/passcode
Exchange id/pass for unique token
Validate token on each subsequent request until it expires
is pretty standard

Comment: @kumar I don't want  to use session storage, What I was doing is after authentication, sending token with every request and this token get resolved at gateway, so how should I get this token at another service?

Comment: @ShaunakPatel Hey, I am sending generated jwt with every request, but at the time of forwarding request from gateway how to add this?

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52624699/spring-security-read-jwt-details/52626769#52626769

Comment: @Habil Hey, I saw your answer in the post, but when I used this function getClaimsFromToken(String token), it is giving me exception: signing key cannot be null or empty. I have declared the secret key in properties file and the  class itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zuul by default does not forwards your **Authorization** header . You will have to explicitly configure in zuul to make it do this. 
Your services must be on different server. 
You have to change sensitve header settings in zuul properties (may be application.yml). By default it takes the following input.

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie,Authorization
      url: https://downstream
```

If you are very sure to forward your header in all services then only change this to

```
zuul:
  routes:
    users:
      path: /myusers/**
      sensitiveHeaders:
      url: https://downstream
```

I hope this helps.